# Android: Push dynamic notifications from background while app is closed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, android-service

I need to send notifications from background, even if the user removed the app from RAM, getting informations (to put in the notification) as Extras from the intents.

Currently it works if the app is opened or opened in background, but it can't get extras while app is closed from recent apps (removed from RAM).

This is the activity that creates the background service and put the ID that I need to transfer as Extra.

**AddEvent.java**

```
// Gets the ID after it was generated by the database
        int ID = newEvent.getID();

        if (newEvent.hasNotification()) {
            // Creates the intent that starts the background service
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);

            // Puts the ID and the Notification Time as Extras and starts the service
            serviceIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID,ID);
            serviceIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TIME,notificationDate.getTimeInMillis());
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }
```

This activity starts an IntentService that I extended.

**NotificationService.java**

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {

public NotificationService() {
    super("Notification Service");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {

    // Create the intent that is going to push the notification, giving it the previous bundle
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPusher.class);

    long notificationTime = workIntent.getLongExtra(ActivityAddEvent.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TIME,-1);
    int ID = workIntent.getIntExtra(ActivityAddEvent.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID,-1);
    Log.d("ID Service",""+ID);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(ActivityAddEvent.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID,ID);

    PendingIntent pusher = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, UniqueID.getUniqueID(),
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //TODO : Can't get the Extras in Pusher
    
    // Sets the alarm for the designed date and time
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,notificationTime,pusher);
}

public static class UniqueID {
    private final static AtomicInteger uniqueID = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public static int getUniqueID() {
        return uniqueID.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

}

It gets the notification time and sets it to the Alarm Manager in order to push the notification at the desired time.

It gets **correctly** the ID and the TIME (as long) then puts the ID in the new intent, which is the notification pusher that issue the notification.

**NotificationPusher.java**

```
public class NotificationPusher extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent workIntent) {

    // Gets the event from the database using the ID received in the intent
    int ID = workIntent.getIntExtra(ActivityAddEvent.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, -1);
    Log.d("ID Pusher", "" + ID);


    EventManager eventManager = EventManager.getInstance(context);
    Event event = null;
    try {
        event = eventManager.getEvent(ID);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO: Add error for id not found
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (event != null) {
        String notificationTitle;
        String notificationText;
        // Sets the notification
        if (event.hasSubject()) {
            notificationTitle = event.getSubject() + "'s " + event.getType().toString();
            notificationText = context.getString(R.string.event_notification_default_text);
        } else {
            notificationTitle = event.getType().toString();
            notificationText = event.getTitle();
        }

        // Create the intent that is gonna be triggered when the notification is clicked and add to the stack
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ActivitySingleEvent.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(ActivityAddEvent.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, ID);

        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, NotificationService.UniqueID.getUniqueID(),
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       
        // Gets the default sound for notifications
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        // Create the notification with a title,icon,text,sound and vibration
        NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_white_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationText)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                // Notification auto cancel itself when clicked
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(uri)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000);

        // Build the notification and issue it
        Notification notification = nBuilder.build();
        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nManager.notify(ID, notification);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(context,"null event",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

}

At the top of the Notification Pusher it tries to get the ID from Extras, but everytime the application is removed from ram, it gets the default value (-1).
I don't know how to pass this ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your service a foreground service, which will most likely require a permanent system notification but it keeps it alive when the app itself is closed.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: So I need to change my IntentService into a normal Service? I already tried it, but how can I add extras to the service if it isn't an Intent?
Edit : Is there any other method that doesn't need a permanent system notification?